# visual studio build application from the source code

Tags: c++, visual-studio, build

I have an application to build using the code source but i have a problem with that because i didn't understand what they mean by:

> On Windows, add `-G "Visual Studio 14 Win64"`. Also, you will probably
>   need to add `-C ../4dface/initial_cache.cmake` as first argument -
>   copy the file from `initial_cache.cmake.template` and adjust the
>   paths.

Here is the third step which i can't realize it:
3.

> Build the app:
>       Run from *outside* the source directory:
>       1. `mkdir build && cd build`
>
> ```
> 2. `cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=../install -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=gcc-5 -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=g++-5 -DOpenCV_haarcascades_DIR=/usr/share/opencv/haarcascades/ ../4dface/`
>
> On Windows, add `-G "Visual Studio 14 Win64"`. Also, you will probably need to add `-C ../4dface/initial_cache.cmake` as first
> ```
>
> argument - copy the file from `initial_cache.cmake.template` and
>   adjust the paths.
>
> ```
> If you get an error about OpenCV\_haarcascades\_DIR, adjust `-DOpenCV_haarcascades_DIR` to point to the directory of
> ```
>
> `haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml` from OpenCV.

I am on windows 8 and i had the code source from this "https://github.com/patrikhuber/4dface"

and here is the link for the readme "https://github.com/patrikhuber/4dface/blob/master/README.md"

Thank you.

Comment: ok i am trying that....

Comment: ***add -G "Visual Studio 14 Win64"*** Should be add -G "Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64" and you add that as a command line argument when you execute cmake-gui from a Visual Studio 2015 x64 command prompt.

Comment: ok i did it and then?

Comment: but i can't open all the folder i can just open one file no?

Comment: configure and generate in cmake-gui. These are buttons in the ide. Then open Visual Studio 2015 and open the solution and build it.

Comment: ***but i can't open all the folder i can just open one file no?*** I have no idea what you mean by that.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to use CMake.  Install it.

From the Visual Studio "Tools" Menu, choose "Visual Studio Command Prompt".

In the window, change directories to the project.

Now enter the command "CMake -G "Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64".

Note:  Cmake wants the "2015" in the phrase.

Comment: Make sure you pick an x64 command prompt since the generator is Win64.

Comment: "In the window, change directories to the project." what do you mean by that?

Comment: For example, my project resides in "C:\mysql-5.7.11".  When I select the "Visual Studio Command Prompt", the directory is: "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\bin>".  So I have to issue the command "cd \mysql-5.7.11" at the prompt to change the directory to the project.  Replace "directory" with "folder" if it makes more sense.

Comment: now i have to install Cmake 2015 for enter the command "CMake -G "Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64" that's it?

Comment: Let me clarify.  The directory you should change to is the directory that requires CMake to run in.  My example project is not my project but MySQL that I am trying to build.

Comment: If you read my answer, you should install `CMake` before you open Visual Studio.

Comment: Install CMake-3.5.0 before you do any of this.

Comment: ok now i have trouble with installing Cmake i get this error :"CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:19 (project):
  No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found."

Comment: Did you run CMake from a Visual Studio 2015 command prompt? A regular windows command prompt will not have the paths and environment variables set correctly. If you did check your Visual Studio 2015 installation.